# 404-resource not found in MVC

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

404-resource not found in MVC using spring
there is no error in any of the file and the code is also correct still getting error. i checked it many times.
below are my web.xml, *-servlet.xml and my beans.xml file

```
*Beans.XML*
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">


    <bean id="product" class="com.shoppingcart.beans.Product">

        <property name="id" value="10"></property>
        <property name="name" value="Apple"></property>

    </bean>

    <bean name="vendor" class="com.shoppingcart.beans.Vendor">
        <property name="name" value="iStore"></property>
        <property name="city" value="Thane"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"></property>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"></property>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"></property>
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver}"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean name="account" class="com.shoppingcart.model.Account"></bean>

    <context:component-scan
        base-package="com.shoppingcart.beans, com.shoppingcart.model, com.shoppingcart.controller">
    </context:component-scan>
    <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
    <context:property-placeholder
        location="com/shoppingcart/main/jdbc.properties" />


</beans>


----------------------------------------------------------------------------
404-resource not found in MVC using spring
```

there is no error in any of the file and the code is also correct still getting error. i checked it many times.
below are my web.xml, *-servlet.xml and my beans.xml file

```
*shoppingcart-servlet.xml*

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.shoppingcart.controller">
    </context:component-scan>
    <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/jsps/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>

----------------------------------------------------------------------------404-resource not found in MVC using spring
```

there is no error in any of the file and the code is also correct still getting error. i checked it many times.
below are my web.xml, *-servlet.xml and my beans.xml file

```
*web.xml*

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>ShoppingCart</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>shoppingcart</display-name>
    <servlet-name>shoppingcart</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>shoppingcart</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Are you following some ancient tutorial?

Comment: No!!!! why you asked though?

Comment: Doesn't look very modern.

Comment: But do you find any logical error that would lead to 404-resource not found exception

Comment: can you post your called url, your servlet and war structure ?

Comment: Try clean and build the project

Answer (score 1):

Where is the index.* files mentioned in the `welcome-file` tag placed ?
when the application starts, it is checking the `welcome-files` mentioned in `web.xml`  inside `WebContent` folder . But if you have placed them inside `WebContent/jsps/` the requested files wont be found. That can cause  a 404.

Solutions:

1.You can move your jsps to `WebContent` directory.
2. In the `welcome-file` tag give the complete path of the index.jsp
Example : `<welcome-file>/jsps/index.jsp</welcome-file>`
3.Since you are using Spring and an `InternalResourceViewResolver` you can also configure a controller to load the welcome page instead of moving the files.
Example :

```
@RequestMapping(value="Login.jsp")
    public ModelAndView showLoginPage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ){
        return new ModelAndView("Login");
    }
```

then accessing the page using the url: 
http://localhost:port/context_root_of_your_application/Login.jsp

Dispatcher Servlet will pick this call -- redirect to controller -- look for the view ("Login" ) inside /jsps/ and if matching jsp is found it will redirect to that jsp.

Hope this helps